# I added a new font, works with the first one

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I added a new font called cgib.ttf, I went to MainActivity.java to add the 2 titleTexts
Here is the activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/titleText"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="55sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kark"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/titleText2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.sa.damas;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initTypeFace();
        }
    private void initTypeFace() {
        Typeface cgib = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/cgib.ttf");


        TextView titleText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleText.setTypeface(cgib);


        TextView titleText2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.kark);
        titleText2.setTypeface(cgib);
    }
}
```

The title is fixed and the second (kark) couldnt be found in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `import android.R;` with `import R;`

android.R contains the system resources, not your project's resources

Comment: Please be more specific, tell us your error. Whatever happens. Do not revert to import android.R; That was completely wrong to begin with.

Comment: By the way, is this your entire XML, you seem to be missing the close tag for RelativeLayout.

Comment: The msg is "Multiple markers are this line - The important 'R' cannot be resolved. - Occurrence of 'R' - Don't include android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead"

Comment: The RelativeLayout is added, I wonder why its not here! But its added

Comment: replace import R; with import com.sa.damas.R;

Comment: "Don't include android.R here;" means that Eclipse is complaining about the same thing I complained about. You should try Project > Clean. and try running it again.  If that still doesn't work, start over from scratch. Create a brand-new 'hello world' android project. Make sure that it runs as is (without any modifications). Make sure that it doesn't try to import android.R; Then add the Text Views one at a time with your font (without messing with the surrounding default linear layout of your 'hello world' project, you can always worry about the formatting of your layout later).

Comment: Stephan, the "import com.sa.damas.R;" worked, the font worked as well, thank you very much .. one more thing, there is a warning that says "This LinearLayout or it's RelativeLayout parent is useless; Transfer the background attribute to the other view" under <LinearLayout as you can see in the code, I have no idea why is it there!